# Effects of calling __init__() from inside the object

Tags: python, constructor, garbage-collection, reset, init

I have a class that I would like to 'reset' at times. Instead of manually clearing out all the variable in the class and all the modules it uses, I thought it might be a good idea to reconstruct it by calling **init** on itself. My concern is that I'm not quite sure if this is a good pattern, or if GC is clearing out the old objects correctly.

An example is below:

```
from modules import SmallClass
from modules import AnotherClass

class BigClass(object):
    def __init__(self, server=None):
        """construct the big class"""
        self.server = server
        self.small_class = SmallClass(self.server)
        self.another_class = AnotherClass(small_class)

    def reset_class(self):
        """reset the big class"""
        self.__init__(self.server)
```

Would this cause problems down the line, or is there a better way of going about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest doing it the other way around:

```
from modules import SmallClass
from modules import AnotherClass

class BigClass(object):
    def __init__(self, server=None):
        """construct the big class"""
        self.reset_class(server)

    def reset_class(self, server=None):
        """reset the big class"""
        self.server = server
        self.small_class = SmallClass(self.server)
        self.another_class = AnotherClass(small_class)
```

This pattern is quite common as it allows `__init__` to reset the class and you can separately reset the class as well. I have also seen this pattern in other object-oriented languages such as Java.

Comment: Side note, that `__init__` should also be calling the `super()`'s init.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure `super()` does not necessarily return the direct parent, if something else has multiple inheritance. E.g. if `C` subclasses both `A` and `B`, which each subclass object, the MRO for `C` may be `C-A-B-object` in which case `super()` in A's `__init__` will return `B`, even though `A` is a subclass of `object` only. The rule of thumb is to *always* call `super()`'s init if you're overriding init.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about that. My mistake. I'll remove my comment.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure Better to leave it as context for others, but too late now I suppose. :)

Comment: As a quick aside, pylint is throwing warnings: `Attribute 'small_class' defined outside __init__ (attribute-defined-outside-init)`. Would it be better to have `self.small_class = None` in `__init__`, and instantiate it in `reset`?

Answer (score 2):

It's safe to do, there's nothing magic about `__init__` other than it's called automatically.

However, the normal thing to do is refactor common code into your `reset_class` method (which i'd call `reset` btw, class is already in the classname). THen just call `reset` from the `__init__` method.